# Error in reading point cloud data (.las) in R?

Tags: r, lidar, las, lidr, rlidar

I want to generate a DEM using a point cloud (.las) for which I tried reading it in R using `rlas`, `lidR` and `rLiDAR` : `readLAS` command and none of it seems to work.

The LASfile is not being read at all. The error is :

```
Error in readBin(con, "raw", size = 1, n = 4, endian = "little") : 
  can only read from a binary connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(LASfile, open = "rb") :
  file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former
```

And the code is:

```
library(lidR)
library(rLiDAR)
library(rlas)
setwd("D:/Thing/Path")
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "ABCD.las", package="rLiDAR")
rLAS <- readLAS(LASfile, short = TRUE)
```

Comment: Without some information about that file we can't help. Is it text or binary? What format is it *supposed* to be?  Do any other files that are *supposed* to be that type work or you? Can we get the file?

Comment: I don't have any other file so I don't know if it works with others. The file is too big and it is .las format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to read the file "ABCD.las" from the package `rLiDAR`. The package `rLiDAR` does not have such file. You probably meant something like:

```
readLAS("D:/Thing/Path/ABCD.las")
```

Also you loaded both `lidR` and `rLiDAR` that both have a `readLAS` function that give two different outputs. You are likely to run into trouble using the two packages simultaneously. In addition `rlas` is the backend that drives read/write of las files in `lidR`. You will almost never need to load this package in your workspace.